# Jest mock function doesn't work while it was called in the other function

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I believe something fundamentally wrong in my understanding for Javascript.

In file abc.js, I have code

```
export function returnBoolean() {
  return true;
}

export function output() {
  return returnBoolean();
}
```

In the test, I do

```
import * as abc from "../abc";

it("test", () => {
  abc.returnBoolean = jest.fn();
  abc.returnBoolean.mockReturnValue(false);
  expect(abc.returnBoolean()).toBe(false); // This is success
  expect(abc.output()).toBe(false); // This failed because return is true
});
```

I don't know why
`abc.output()` return is `true`.

I am really confused. Any thought is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`output()` and `returnBoolean()` are both in the same file and `output()` calls `returnBoolean()` directly.

Mocking the module export for `returnBoolean()` doesn't have any effect on `output()` since it is not using the module, it is calling `returnBoolean()` directly.

Like felixmosh said, moving `returnBoolean()` to a different module is one way to be able to mock the call to `returnBoolean()` within `output()`.

The other way is to simply import the module back into itself and use the module to call `returnBoolean()` within `output()` like this:

```
// import the module back into itself
import * as abc from './abc';

export function returnBoolean() {
  return true;
}

export function output() {
  return abc.returnBoolean(); // use the module to call returnBoolean()
}
```

With this approach your unit test should work.

Comment: @KunYuTsai let me know if this makes sense and if you have any more questions

Comment: "import the module back into itself" ?  what?

Answer (score 4):

Think about it, whenever you import `abc` module, all the function inside that module are declared, therefore, `output` function get "bounded" to the original returnBoolean.

Your mock won't apply on the original function.

You have 2 choices:

1. If the `returnBoolean` can be on a separate module, you will able to use [jest's mocking mechnisem](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks).
2. If you able to change the interface of `output` method so it will be able to get the `returnBoolean` from outside of the module.
   Then you will be able to pass to it, `jest.fn()` and make your expectation on it.

Comment: **whenever you import abc module, all the function inside that module are declared, therefore, output function get "bounded" to the original returnBoolean.**

Thanks for the precious hint. However, by any chance you could give me more explanation for that sentence? I can't quite understand it.

Comment: Think of that as when you require file, the process behind the scene stops, read the file, load it into memory and executes it. Whenever it executed, the way you wrote the function out, it uses the “pointer” to the fonction from the module.

Comment: Therefore, if later on you are trying to change that pointer, you won’t affect pointer that “out” function burned in it self. Hope it makes that more clear.